# GCP: Reverse Proxy on VM in front of Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

We run a Kubernetes cluster hosting a database, various microservices and an `nginx` reverse proxy, all in containers. We have a Google [load balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-loadbalancer) and a forwarding rule that forwards to the reverse proxy, and from there requests are proxied to the appropriate microservice.

This works well, however the reverse proxy is never shown the IP address of clients connecting to it. (Despite [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/) indicating that it is possible to obtain this information via HTTP headers, we've had no luck and only ever see IPs on our GCP `default` network.)

Following a suggestion in another SO question - whose link I've temporarily mislaid - I want to deploy `nginx` on a VM instance instead, where it *does* have access to a connecting client's IP, and then forward requests from that instance into the cluster.

My question then is this: Each microservice listens on a TCP port and has a k8s `Service` configured. How can I refer to these k8s `Service`s from within my `nginx` VM? Can I do it via DNS or via ingress controllers?

Alternatively if you *can* in fact determine external IP addresses behind a Google Load balancer I'd much rather do that. I remember reading a very long k8s GitHub issue about it showing that that was some way off yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `http proxy protocol`

https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/proxy-protocol/

Note that both google load balancer and your nginx must be configured to use the proxy protocol at the same time.
If one of them is using proxy protocol, and the other not using, nothing will work.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware of that. Unfortunately I could not configure the LB to support this (it seems like I might need the Google LB to do TLS termination and I cannot do it myself, which is not an option for us). Currently I've managed to get the VM outside the cluster to connect to a k8s `Service` (type `NodePort`) inside the cluster but it's very hacky; the endpoint IP for the Service changes every time the k8s Deployment is upgraded.

Comment: My first LB solution included proxy protocol. It worked but it was not acceptable for us because of similar reasons. Nowdays I just create instance group in k8s cluster and dedicate them as loadbalancers.

Comment: For others who stumble across this, I fixed the issues around the IP moving by looking up `/endpoints/` via `curl` when determining the IP to forward to from the proxy. We use the PROXY protocol now to forward the source IP address to the k8s services and it works great :-)